# POST data not pushed to POST array

Tags: php, arrays, post, multidimensional-array

I am saving content items with a title and content value in a database. In my example you can see that I have one item for creating a new content item and the earlier saved items.

I save the items in a multidimensional array by adding the index in each input's name field like `<input name="extra[2][title]">` (see example).

For the creating fields I try to store a new item with a new key by doing `<input name="extra[][title]">`, which normally pushes a new item to the end of an array. But when I print out the POST data the new item is not there, so I cannot store it in the array with the other items.

**HTML FORM:**

```
<form method="post">

    <!-- This is for creating a new item -->
    <div class="item">
        <input type="text" name="extra[][title]">
        <input type="text" name="extra[][content]">
    </div><!--End .item-->


    <!-- Items from array -->
    <?php
    $extras = array( /* Earlier saved items */ );
    foreach( $extras as $index => $extra ) { ?>

        <div class="item">
            <input type="text" name="extra[<?php echo $index; ?>][title]">
            <input type="text" name="extra[<?php echo $index; ?>][content]">
        </div><!--End .item-->

    <?php   
    }
    ?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

**After doing this, the new item is not there:**

```
<?php
if( ! empty( $_POST['extra'] ) ) {

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $_POST['extra'] );
    echo '</pre>';

}
?>
```

**print_r( $_POST ) returns:**

```
Array
(
    [extra] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Test 1
                    [content] => test content
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [content] => test content
                    [title] => Test 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Test 3
                    [content] => test content
                )

        )

    [submit] => submit
)
```

Comment: Try looking in `print_r($_POST);` and see what is in there.

Comment: Check my question. I checked the POST result already.

Comment: Robbert, So show it to use as well, a `print_r($_POST);` that is

Comment: @Robbert No, you tried to look in `$_POST['extra']`. Now go look in `$_POST`.

Comment: bro you code actually works.. check the input array maybe

Comment: @Robert i have made some changes in code hope will help you.!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Check my edit.

Comment: Robbert: Does that no answer all your questions? I personally dont think you need the [extra] bit at all I would just use `newtitle[]` and `newcomment[]`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I need that for sure. Because I save this at the same time with other values. otherwise I cannot make distinction between all POST data.

Comment: @RiggsFolly maybe that's a good one. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Check my answer. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of RiggsFolly, I created this solution, which is very simple.

**I changed the form html to this:**

```
<form method="post">

    <!-- This is for creating a new item -->
    <div class="item">
        <input type="text" name="extra_title[]">
        <input type="text" name="extra_content[]">
    </div><!--End .item-->


    <!-- Items from array -->
    <?php
    $extras = array( 
        array(
            'title' => 'Test 1',
            'content' => 'test content'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Test 2',
            'content' => 'test content'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Test 3',
            'content' => 'test content'
        )


    );
    foreach( $extras as $index => $extra ) { ?>

        <div class="item">
            <input type="text" name="extra_content[]" value="<?php echo $extra['title']; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="extra_title[]" value="<?php echo $extra['content']; ?>">
        </div><!--End .item-->

    <?php   
    }
    ?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

**The POST outputs this:**

```
Array
(
    [extra_title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test 4
            [1] => Test 1
            [2] => Test 2
            [3] => Test 3
        )

    [extra_content] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tkldmsd
            [1] => test content
            [2] => test content
            [3] => test content
        )

    [submit] => submit
)
```

And then you can combine those values by index as follows:

```
<?php
if( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $_POST );
    echo '</pre>';

    if( ! empty( $_POST['extra_title'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['extra_content'] ) ) {

        $extra = array();

        foreach( $_POST['extra_title'] as $index => $title ) {

            $extra[$index] = array(
                'title' => $title,
                'content' => $_POST['extra_content'][$index]
            );

        }


    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have gavethe key in php created input while it will not work so you have to leave key blank just give its value

**this is working code for your need**

```
<form method="post">

    <!-- This is for creating a new item -->
    <div class="item">
        <input type="text" name="extra[0][title]">
        <input type="text" name="extra[0][content]">
    </div><!--End .item-->


    <!-- Items from array -->
    <?php
    $extras=array(0=>'aa',1=>'bb');
    $i=1;
    foreach( $extras as $index => $extra ) { ?>

        <div class="item">
            <input type="text" name="extra[<?php echo $i ?>][title]" value="<?php echo $extra; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="extra[<?php echo $i ?>][content]" value="<?php echo $extra; ?>">
        </div><!--End .item-->

    <?php   
     $i++;}
    ?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
<?php
if( ! empty( $_POST['extra'] ) ) {

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $_POST['extra'] );
    echo '</pre>';

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this is not the best option. I had this in mind, but I am looking for the best.

Answer (score 0):

It's your code, and it works. Just php now check for "isset".

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST ) ) {

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $_POST["extra"] );
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>


<form method="post">

<!-- This is for creating a new item -->
<div class="item">
    <input type="text" name="extra[][title]">
    <input type="text" name="extra[][content]">
</div><!--End .item-->


<!-- Items from array -->
<?php
$extras = array( "alfa","beta" );
foreach( $extras as $index => $extra ) { ?>

    <div class="item">
        <input type="text" name="extra[<?php echo $index; ?>][title]">
        <input type="text" name="extra[<?php echo $index; ?>][content]">
    </div><!--End .item-->

<?php   
}
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Check his `$_POST` dump it changes the addressing of your answer